# Group data based on property javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have json array as follows,

```
{
      "lstMonths": [
        "September"
      ],
      "lstBalances": [
        {
          "AccountName": "john",
          "AccountBalanceOnMonth": [
            {
              "MonthName": "September",
              "Amount": "-28.11"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "AccountName": "sanga\n",
          "AccountBalanceOnMonth": [
            {
              "MonthName": "September",
              "Amount": "100"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "AccountName": "mahela",
          "AccountBalanceOnMonth": [
            {
              "MonthName": "September",
              "Amount": "400"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "AccountName": "sachin",
          "AccountBalanceOnMonth": [
            {
              "MonthName": "September",
              "Amount": "600"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "AccountName": "dhoni",
          "AccountBalanceOnMonth": [
            {
              "MonthName": "September",
              "Amount": "-500"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

i want to group by AccountName and form the output as,

```
  { data: [28.11], label: 'john' },
  { data: [100], label: 'sanga' },
  { data: [400], label: 'mahela' },
  { data: [400], label: 'sachin' }
  { data: [400], label: 'dhoni' }
```

if there are two months, say october in above then

```
  { data: [28.11,3], label: 'john' },
  { data: [100,4], label: 'sanga' },
  { data: [400,4], label: 'mahela' },
  { data: [400,4], label: 'sachin' }
  { data: [400,5], label: 'dhoni' }
```

i tried to group like as above. any help guys?

here is my code:

```
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
console.log(groupBy(response.lstMonths, 'length'));
```

please provide a way to find the best value.

**EDIT**

json for more months,

> {   "lstMonths": [
>       "September"   ],   "lstBalances": [
>       {
>         "AccountName": "john\n",
>         "AccountBalanceOnMonth": [
>           {
>             "MonthName": "September",
>             "Amount": "-28.11"
>           },
>           {
>             "MonthName": "August",
>             "Amount": "-28.11"
>           }
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "AccountName": "sanga\n",
>         "AccountBalanceOnMonth": [
>           {
>             "MonthName": "September",
>             "Amount": "100"
>           },
>           {
>             "MonthName": "August",
>             "Amount": "233"
>           }
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "AccountName": "mahela",
>         "AccountBalanceOnMonth": [
>           {
>             "MonthName": "September",
>             "Amount": "400"
>           },
>           {
>             "MonthName": "August",
>             "Amount": "32"
>           }
>         ]
>       }   ] }

Comment: for more months, please supply an example of data.

Comment: How is the `data` property generated? Please explain and recheck the values.

Comment: @NinaScholz added the json

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir data is generated from the amount, actually those are dummy values.i just want to get it from the amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming,

- only one array with data,
- for every month is a value,
- all months are sorted
- result months should have the same sorting,

then you could take the array with accounts and iterate the accounts for building a new object for each account and take the balance values for the data array.

```js
var data = [{ lstMonths: ["September"], lstBalances: [{ AccountName: "john", AccountBalanceOnMonth: [{ MonthName: "September", Amount: "-28.11" }, { MonthName: "August", Amount: "-28.11" }] }, { AccountName: "sanga", AccountBalanceOnMonth: [{ MonthName: "September", Amount: "100" }, { MonthName: "August", Amount: "233" }] }, { AccountName: "mahela", AccountBalanceOnMonth: [{ MonthName: "September", Amount: "400" }, { MonthName: "August", Amount: "32" }] }] }],
    grouped = data[0].lstBalances.map(function (o) {
        return {
            data: o.AccountBalanceOnMonth.map(function (p) { return +p.Amount; }),
            label: o.AccountName
        };
    });
    
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```